# How to get lows and highs of before and after bars in PineScript

Tags: pine-script

I executed the script below but the expected chart is not available. I need to display last two Highs and Lows of the chart. This is not the complete script.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Turning Points", shorttitle="TP", overlay=true)

isTurningUp = low > low[1] and low > low[1] + 2
isTurningDown = high > high[1] and high > high[1] + 1

// Plotting symbols at turning points
plotshape(series=isTurningUp ? low : na, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small, title="Turning Up", location=location.belowbar, offset=-1)
plotshape(series=isTurningDown ? high : na, color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.small, title="Turning Down", location=location.abovebar, offset=-1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
isTurningUp = low > low[1] and low > low[1] + 2
isTurningDown= high > high[1] and high > high[1] + 1
```

This section doesn't make sense, you cant add integers to a True/False statement. The `ta.valuewhen(boolean,value,occurence)` function is what you want I believe.

```
isTurningUp = low > low[1] and low[1] < low[2]      #Replace these with 
isTurningDown= high < high[1] and high[1] > high[2] #whatever you want

Highs_n_Lows(upBool,dnBool,Occurrence1=0,Occurrence2=1)=> # Occurence 0 is 
                                                              #most recent,  
                                                              #1 is second 
                                                              #most recent, 
    Dn1=ta.valuewhen(dnBool,high,Occurrence1)                 #etc etc.
    Dn2=ta.valuewhen(dnBool,high,Occurrence2) 
    Up1=ta.valuewhen(upBool,low,Occurrence1)
    Up2=ta.valuewhen(upBool,low,Occurrence2)

    [Up1,Dn1,Up2,Dn2]

[Up1,Dn1,Up2,Dn2] = Highs_n_Lows(isTurningUp,isTurningDown,)


plot(Up1)
plot(Dn1)
plot(Up2)
plot(Dn2)
```